# Existence of invertible operator on Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $H_1 ,H_2$ are two closed subspaces of $\mathcal{H}$. Then $\mathcal{H}=H_1\oplus H_1^\perp=H_2\oplus H_2^\perp.$

My questions:

1. If $dim(H_1)=dim(H_2)$ is finite, then is $dim(H_1^\perp)=dim(H_2^\perp)$  true ?
2. If $dim(H_1)=dim(H_2)$ , then does there exist an invertible operator $T :H_1\rightarrow H_2?$

If $\mathcal{H}$ is finite dimensional , both  are true . If $\mathcal{H}$ is infinite dimensional, I don't know whether my 1st question is valid or not. Kindly make me clarify.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming that the dimension is defined as $\infty$ if the space is infinite dimensional: The first question is still valid and both dimensions must be equal to the same value (which one?) if $\mathcal{H}$ is infinite dimensional. You can show this by assuming that this was not the case.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes to both.  For any orthonormal subset $S\subseteq H$ there exists, by Zorn's lemma, a maximal orthonormal subset $T$ containing $S$.  A maximal orthonormal subset $T$ of $H$ is an orthonormal basis.  To see this, let  $W$ be the closure of the linear span of $T$.  If $W\ne H$ then $W^\perp \ne \{0\}$, and any vector in $W^\perp$ of norm $1$ extends the orthonormal set $T$ - contradicting its maximality.

All orthonormal bases of $H$ have the same cardinality.  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232166).

So let $V_1$ be an orthonormal basis of $H_1$ and $V_2$ be an orthonormal basis of $H_2$.  Since $\dim H_1 = \dim H_2$, $|V_1| = |V_2|$.  $V_1$ and $V_2$ each extend to orthonormal bases $B_1, B_2$ of $H$.  Since all orthonormal bases have the same cardinality $|B_1| = |B_2|$, and since $|V_1|=|V_2|$ are finite, by cardinal arithmetic we must have $\kappa=|B_1\setminus V_1|=|B_2\setminus V_2|$.  So $H_1^\perp, H_2^\perp$ have the same orthogonal dimension $\kappa$.  If $\Pi:B_1\setminus V_1\to B_2\setminus V_2$ is any bijection, then $\Pi$ extends uniquely to a partial isometry of $H_1^\perp$ onto $H_2^\perp$.  Any invertible operator $T:H_1\to H_2$ can be extended to an invertible operator on $H$ by acting as $\Pi$ on $H_1^\perp$.

Comment: In last paragraph , u have mentioned $\pi$ extends uniquely to a unitary mapping .That means if I set $\pi(f_i)=g_j ,$ then $\pi^*(g_j)=f_i$ such that $\pi \pi^*=I  $ and $\pi^*\pi=I$. Am i right ?

Comment: Yes, nearly, but I changed the term to 'partial isometry' instead of 'unitary mapping'.  $\Pi^* \Pi = P_{H_1^\perp}$ and $\Pi \,\Pi^* = P_{H_2^\perp}$ where $P_{xx}$ are the orthogonal projections on these subspaces.